# Automatic scrolling animation of the text in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a long string:

```
"A very long string"
```

that won't be displayed fully in a `UITableView`, i.e. it gets truncated to:

```
"A very long s..."
```

Is it possible to have this text in a `UITableViewCell` automatically scroll horizontally and indefinitely so that it loops around? Perhaps this can be achieved using an attributed string?

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "A very long string"
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

**EDIT (my attempt at a solution proposed)**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath)

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: cell.bounds.width * 2.0, height: cell.bounds.height)

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: frame)
    cell.addSubview(scrollView)

    let label = UILabel(frame: scrollView.bounds)
    scrollView.addSubview(label)
    label.text = "some very long text that doesn't quite fit"
    label.textAlignment = .center

    let newFrame = CGRect(x: label.frame.width, y: 0, width: label.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations:( { void in
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(newFrame, animated: true)}),
        completion: ({ completed in }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview inside a table view is a bad idea. Instead you can enable the automaticDimension and estimated row height and tableView will manage the cell height automatically.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

So as per the content each cell will manage its own height.

Hope this would be helpful!

Comment: is there no way to have a scrolling animation?

Comment: Second way is to add a scrollView in a table view cell. And add a UILabel inside scrollView and maintain its contentView depending upon UILabel width.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a custom tableview cell, which has a custom scrollview which handles UILabel scrolling.  You would need to assign the text and measure the width.  If it is wider than the containing view then add a second duplicate label to its right.  You then need to animate the scrollview to the left by the width of the label.  On complete, jump back to offset 0,0 and animate again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried to implement it but I can't get the animation to continue triggering after they've been set up. Could you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to have special effect as such will require customization of an UILabel. To make my life easier, I will always try to search if there is already a working library out there for me to consume.

A simple Google search brings me [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel), hope it helps!